# Throw exception by condition. Spring web flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I have the following reactive code. And I want to throw my custom exception, if return value is null

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .map(authentication ->(UserAuthenticationToken) authentication)
                .map(UserAuthenticationToken::getUserPrincipalName)
                //Here I want to throw exception, if 
                 //UserAuthenticationToken::getUserPrincipalName will return null
```

something like :

```
 .map(UserAuthenticationToken::getUserPrincipalName)
               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new MissingPrincipalException("Missing email field in the JWT token")));
```

or :

```
.map(UserAuthenticationToken::getUserPrincipalName)
               .filter(principal -> !Objects.isNull(principal))
               .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new MissingPrincipalException("Missing email field in the JWT token")))
```

does not work.

Comment: `does not work` means what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reactive streams specification disallows `null` values in a sequence, therefore you can't use `map(UserAuthenticationToken::getUserPrincipalName)`.

One way to handle such case is to use `flatMap`

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
     .map(ctx -> (UserAuthenticationToken) ctx.getAuthentication())
     .flatMap(token -> {
        if (token.getUserPrincipalName() == null) {
             return Mono.error(new MissingPrincipalException("Missing email field in the JWT token"));
        }
        
        return Mono.just(token.getUserPrincipalName());
     })
```

You can also use `handle` operator  to remove any nulls. Reactor Reference Guide has a good example for [Using handle for a "map and eliminate nulls" scenario](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_handle)